# Add external classes to exisiting project

Tags: java, android, jar

I received recently a custom SDK from a manufacturer. I used it in my project but I noticed the classes I need are not included in the given jar.

Basically in my platforms folder, I have an android 2.3.5 repository including a jar, 4 files (build.prop, framework.aidl, sdk.properties, source.properties and repositories containing the custom classs I need.

Am I supposed to build a jar file with those? I have an existing manifest.xml file with my project, is that what causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your library as android project into eclipse, then you can mark "isLibrary" in the project-properties. This allows you to include the project as library in your main-project.

Comment: OK Nickolaus, I'm sorry to ask (this is new to me) but should I import the whole thing?